# Python - resubmit future on timeout

Tags: python, concurrency, timeout, future, pool

Currently, I am using futures in Python in order to connect to (and analyse) multiple sites at the same time.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 8) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(analyser.analyse, name, aggregator, past, current):
                       (name, aggregator) for name, aggregator in aggregators.iteritems()}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            records += future.result()
```

However, the futures sometimes get "stuck" on certain webpages, at least that is my assumption. (Generally, the problem I am trying to solve is that when the script is launched from cronjob, the processes sometimes get stuck).

What I want to do, though, is to implement a "timeout" for certain futures, so if it exceeds its time limits, the future is submitted to the pool again.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 8) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(analyser.analyse, name, aggregator, past, current):
                       (name, aggregator) for name, aggregator in aggregators.iteritems()}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                records += future.result(timeout = 30)
            except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
                if DEBUG:
                    print("Future took too long, retrying!")
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to resubmit a future back to the pool, as executor only accepts "raw" objects, and not futures. Is there any Pythonic way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

There no way to resubmit because you don't have to: it will stay in the pool unless you cancel it explicitly. more: [How to use concurrent.futures with timeouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509261/how-to-use-concurrent-futures-with-timeouts)