How to init Pool() inside child daemonic, but only once?
On python 3.11 and Ubuntu I have a task to init asynchronous calls every time interval (not asyncio) and inside child do multiprocessing task. I have 36 cores / 72 processors. The problem is when I init new Pool(72) it takes 0.3 seconds that is too much for my task, because performance matters. With this article Python Process Pool non-daemonic? I found out how to do new pool inside pool (using NoDaemonProcess). But how to init child pool only once? concurrent.futures does not good for me, because I made test and it's slower than multiprocessing.
Here is working example, I need to modify somehow to init pool inside child only once.
parent pid=907058

2024-06-01 19:16:44.856839 start
2024-06-01 19:16:44.861229 sleep 4 sec
2024-06-01 19:16:44.861777 [907059] on_message(): 1
2024-06-01 19:16:44.866430 [907059] starting pool..
2024-06-01 19:16:44.867275 worker_function(), a=907059_1
2024-06-01 19:16:44.867373 worker_function(), a=907059_2
2024-06-01 19:16:44.867410 worker_function(), a=907059_3

2024-06-01 19:16:48.861738 start
2024-06-01 19:16:48.864965 sleep 4 sec
2024-06-01 19:16:48.865581 [907070] on_message(): 2
2024-06-01 19:16:48.870826 [907070] starting pool..
2024-06-01 19:16:48.871544 worker_function(), a=907070_1
2024-06-01 19:16:48.871638 worker_function(), a=907070_2
2024-06-01 19:16:48.871695 worker_function(), a=907070_3

2024-06-01 19:16:52.865456 long sleep..
2024-06-01 19:16:56.867489 end worker_function(), a=907059_1
2024-06-01 19:16:56.867657 end worker_function(), a=907059_3
2024-06-01 19:16:56.867666 end worker_function(), a=907059_2
2024-06-01 19:16:56.868269 [907059] pool ended
2024-06-01 19:16:56.870487 [907059] finished on_message(): 1
2024-06-01 19:17:00.871746 end worker_function(), a=907070_1
2024-06-01 19:17:00.871896 end worker_function(), a=907070_2
2024-06-01 19:17:00.871903 end worker_function(), a=907070_3
2024-06-01 19:17:00.872659 [907070] pool ended
2024-06-01 19:17:00.874545 [907070] finished on_message(): 2
2024-06-01 19:17:12.865676 finished

Code:
import os
import time
import traceback
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing.pool

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974695/python-process-pool-non-daemonic
class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    @property
    def daemon(self):
        return False
    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, value):
        pass

class NoDaemonContext(type(multiprocessing.get_context())):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

class NestablePool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = NoDaemonContext()
        super(NestablePool, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Message():

    def __init__(self):

        # self.pool_3 = Pool(3)
        pass

    def worker_function(self, a):

        print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} worker_function(), a={a}")
        time.sleep(12)
        print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} end worker_function(), a={a}")

        return None

    def on_message(self, message):

        try:
            pid = os.getpid()
            print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] on_message(): {message}")

            # I need to make code that here I don't init new Pool()
            # because my server has 72 logic processos and it takes 300ms to init
            # for my task it's super long, so I want to init Pool() once, but not everytime when calling on_message()

            # this could be possible solution
            # but it does not work, in __init__() the Pool(3) is not initing
            # res = self.pool_3.starmap_async(self.worker_function, [(f"{pid}_1",),(f"{pid}_2",),(f"{pid}_3",)]).get()
            # if I init Pool with self. here, I will get error
            # "Pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled"

            with Pool(3) as pool:
                print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] starting pool..")
                res = pool.starmap_async(self.worker_function, [(f"{pid}_1",),(f"{pid}_2",),(f"{pid}_3",)]).get()
                print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] pool ended")

            print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] finished on_message(): {message}")
            # os.kill(pid, 9)
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            print(e)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(f"parent pid={os.getpid()}")
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44719580/1802225 process.terminate()

    me = Message()
    
    for i in range(1, 3):
        print()
        print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} start")
        # starting pool non-daemonic to start pool inside
        pool = NestablePool(1)
        pool.starmap_async(me.on_message, [(i,)])

        print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} sleep 4 sec")
        time.sleep(4)
    
    print()
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} long sleep..")
    time.sleep(20)
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} finished")
       


Another answers code (modified) that works not as expected:
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
from datetime import datetime
import traceback
import time
import os

def convert_char_to_integer(ch):

    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] convert_char_to_integer(), ch={ch}")
    time.sleep(12)  # Simulate real processing
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch={ch}")
    
    return ch

def on_message(multiprocessing_pool, message):

    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] on_message(): {message}")

    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] starting pool..")
    result = multiprocessing_pool.starmap_async(convert_char_to_integer, [(f"{pid}_1",),(f"{pid}_2",),(f"{pid}_3",)]).get()
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} [{pid}] pool ended")
    

def await_next_message():
    yield 'Message 1'
    time.sleep(.1)
    yield 'Message 2'
    time.sleep(.1)
    yield 'Message 3'

def main():
    # Pool(3) must be 3 (let's say it's maxumim cpu's I have)
    # if I set Pool(9) it will work correct, but this way is false, because it collects +3 +3.. pool that can be used
    # that does not good for me, because in real task I use all CPUs
    # and I need to execute pools independently of each other
    with Pool(3) as multiprocessing_pool, ThreadPool(3) as multithreading_pool:
        for message in await_next_message():
            print()
            print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} start")
            multithreading_pool.apply_async(on_message, args=(multiprocessing_pool, message))
            print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} sleep 4 sec")
            time.sleep(4)
        # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete
        multithreading_pool.close()
        multithreading_pool.join()
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Result:
2024-06-03 20:41:26.731560 start
2024-06-03 20:41:26.731670 sleep 4 sec
2024-06-03 20:41:26.731726 [27211] on_message(): Message 1
2024-06-03 20:41:26.731838 [27211] starting pool..
2024-06-03 20:41:26.732411 [27212] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
2024-06-03 20:41:26.732582 [27213] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
2024-06-03 20:41:26.732634 [27214] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3

2024-06-03 20:41:30.832071 start
2024-06-03 20:41:30.832175 sleep 4 sec
2024-06-03 20:41:30.832264 [27211] on_message(): Message 2
2024-06-03 20:41:30.832343 [27211] starting pool..

# (!) HERE is not expected behavior. It must be:
# convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
# convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
# convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3
# , but that is not happening, because it is waiting 3 processes to be ending ("end convert_char_to_integer()"), but I need to work them independently

2024-06-03 20:41:34.932409 start
2024-06-03 20:41:34.932532 sleep 4 sec
2024-06-03 20:41:34.932644 [27211] on_message(): Message 3
2024-06-03 20:41:34.932712 [27211] starting pool..
2024-06-03 20:41:38.732708 [27212] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
2024-06-03 20:41:38.732865 [27213] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
2024-06-03 20:41:38.732895 [27214] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3
2024-06-03 20:41:38.733189 [27212] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
2024-06-03 20:41:38.733256 [27214] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
2024-06-03 20:41:38.733299 [27213] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3
2024-06-03 20:41:38.733613 [27211] pool ended
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733313 [27212] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733415 [27214] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733449 [27213] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733624 [27212] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733642 [27214] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733668 [27213] convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3
2024-06-03 20:41:50.733868 [27211] pool ended
2024-06-03 20:42:02.733748 [27212] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_1
2024-06-03 20:42:02.733746 [27214] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_2
2024-06-03 20:42:02.733757 [27213] end convert_char_to_integer(), ch=27211_3
2024-06-03 20:42:02.734315 [27211] pool ended


You haven't really shown how on_message gets invoked in your actual application. The name of the function suggests that it is invoked when a new message is received from somewhere. Why can't on_message be executed in a multithreading pool if we pass to it additionally a multiprocessing pool instance that has been pre-allocated and which does the CPU-intensive processing? For example:
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
import time
import os

def convert_char_to_integer(ch):
    time.sleep(.3)  # Simulate real processing
    print(f'ch = {ch}, pid = {os.getpid()}, time = {time.time()}')
    return ord(ch)

def on_message(multiprocessing_pool, message):
    # Get the sum of each character of the message after it has been
    # converted to an integer:
    result = sum(multiprocessing_pool.map(convert_char_to_integer, message))
    print(f'{message!r}: {result}')

def await_next_message():
    yield 'Message 1'
    time.sleep(.1)
    yield 'Message 2'
    time.sleep(.1)
    yield 'Message 3'

def main():
    # The pools are started only once using the
    # with Pool() .... statement
    print('starting pools')
    with Pool(10) as multiprocessing_pool, \
    ThreadPool(3) as multithreading_pool:
        for message in await_next_message():
            multithreading_pool.apply_async(on_message, args=(multiprocessing_pool, message))
        # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete
        multithreading_pool.close()
        multithreading_pool.join()
    # Both pools are now terminated
    print('pools ended')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
starting pools
ch = M, pid = 18776, time = 1717442160.0104358
ch = e, pid = 17232, time = 1717442160.0540285
ch = s, pid = 24404, time = 1717442160.0580287
ch = s, pid = 10336, time = 1717442160.0828772
ch = a, pid = 19348, time = 1717442160.126844
ch = g, pid = 14968, time = 1717442160.126844
ch = e, pid = 5600, time = 1717442160.1278431
ch =  , pid = 23884, time = 1717442160.1293561
ch = 1, pid = 3900, time = 1717442160.1298823
ch = M, pid = 15160, time = 1717442160.1299446
'Message 1': 790
ch = e, pid = 18776, time = 1717442160.3112478
ch = s, pid = 17232, time = 1717442160.3551002
ch = s, pid = 24404, time = 1717442160.3591855
ch = a, pid = 10336, time = 1717442160.3840768
ch = e, pid = 14968, time = 1717442160.4282424
ch =  , pid = 5600, time = 1717442160.4282424
ch = g, pid = 19348, time = 1717442160.4282424
ch = 2, pid = 23884, time = 1717442160.4301693
ch = e, pid = 15160, time = 1717442160.4309397
ch = M, pid = 3900, time = 1717442160.4309397
'Message 2': 791
ch = s, pid = 18776, time = 1717442160.6133676
ch = s, pid = 17232, time = 1717442160.6570253
ch = a, pid = 24404, time = 1717442160.6604424
ch = g, pid = 10336, time = 1717442160.6856165
ch = e, pid = 14968, time = 1717442160.7294924
ch = 3, pid = 19348, time = 1717442160.7315066
ch =  , pid = 5600, time = 1717442160.7315066
'Message 3': 792
pools ended


Hi! Thank you for answer, I edited my post with your code to show why it acts not as expected.

You say "it acts not as expected." What are you expecting.? You say, ... because it is waiting 3 processes to be ending ("end convert_char_to_integer()"), but I need to work them independently.  First, this is not clear. Second, your code's 'starting pool ...' and 'pool ended' messages are totally misplaced; no pools are starting and ending where you print this out. Read my updated answer carefully where I show the PID and time. What would you expect to be different? The convert_to_integer calls are being performed in parallel.

You have in on_message: result = multiprocessing_pool.starmap_async(convert_char_to_integer, [(f"{pid}_1",),(f"{pid}_2",),(f"{pid}_3",)]).get(). pid is the process id of the process that is making this call and regardless of which thread within the multithreading pool is executing on_message, that process that own the thread will always be the main process. Printing out this pid is meaningless.

Calling result = multiprocessing_pool.starmap_async(...).get() is exactly equivalent to result = multiprocessing.starmap(...). And result = multiprocessing.starmap(worker, [(a,), (b,), (c,) is equivalent to multiprocessing.map(worker, [a, b, c]). You need to think about this.

I think I figured out what to do, thank you for pointing ThreadPool.
